# Binding a field to a reactive form does not show value

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

If I hardcode the value to something like 'xxx' it is fine. But when I call a service and then try to bind the value nothing happens. I thought it was data bound so when the field is set it would show on the UI ?

```
      <form [formGroup]="saveFileForm" (ngSubmit)="onExpSubmit()">
<div class="row" style="padding: 40px;">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                Notes:
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" formControlName="Notes">
            </div>
        </div>

fileData: AttachmentVm = new AttachmentVm();

  constructor(private service: AttachService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    public dialogRefSpinner: MatDialogRef<DialogRedirectToLandingSpinnerModule>,
    public snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.saveFileForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      PaymentDate: [''],
      IsPaid: [false],
      Notes: [this.fileData.GlobalNotes],
      //Notes: ['xxx'],
      FileDescription: ['']
    });

    if (this.formIdFromParent) {
      this.service.getFiles(this.formIdFromParent).subscribe(result => {
        this.fileData = result;
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: Inside subscribe you need to set value of Notes form control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the form control value:

```
if (this.formIdFromParent) {
  this.service.getFiles(this.formIdFromParent).subscribe(result => {
     this.fileData = result;
     this.formIdFromParent.controls['Notes'].setValue(this.fileData. GlobalNotes);
  })
}
```

Comment: Thats works.. Though in my reading they were talking about using PatchValue for some reason..

Comment: Good!. Yes other option is this.formIdFromParent.patchValue({Notes: this.fileData. GlobalNotes})